# define your own tag in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

There are Tags as in `#+AUTHOR` or `#+LATEX` in org-mode - are they called tags? I'd like to define my own tag which calls a function to preprocess the data and then outputs it - if the export target is LaTeX.

Comment: I don't think they're called `tags`, as `tags` is what are called :stuff: in headlines, which the agenda can filter on, for instance. Maybe [export keywords](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-options.html#Export-options) rather.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was defining an own language, `qtree`, for `SRC` blocks.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC qtree
[.CP [.TP [.NP [] [.N' [.N Syntax] []]] [.VP [] [.V' [.V sucks] []]]]]
#+END_SRC
```

And process it accordingly. I even added a qtree-mode with `paredit`.
And a `landscape` parameter if the trees grow big. https://github.com/Tass/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/vendor/assorted/org-babel-qtree.el

```
(require 'org)

(defun org-babel-execute:qtree (body params)
  "Reformat a block of lisp-edited tree to one tikz-qtree likes."
  (let (( tree
          (concat "\\begin{tikzpicture}
\\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\\Tree "
                  (replace-regexp-in-string
                   " \\_<\\w+\\_>" (lambda (x) (concat "\\\\\\\\" (substring x 1))) 
                   (replace-regexp-in-string
                    (regexp-quote "]") " ]" ; qtree needs a space
                                        ; before every closing
                                        ; bracket.
                    (replace-regexp-in-string
                     (regexp-quote "[]") "[.{}]" body)) ; empty leaf
                                        ; nodes, see
                                        ; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75915
                   )                    ; For
                                        ; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75217
                  "\n\\end{tikzpicture}"
                  )))
    (if (assoc :landscape params)
        (concat "\\begin{landscape}\n" tree "\n\\end{landscape}")
      tree)))

(setq org-babel-default-header-args:qtree '((:results . "latex") (:exports . "results")))
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("qtree" . qtree))
(define-generic-mode 
    'qtree-mode                  ;; name of the mode to create
  '("%")                         ;; comments start with '%'
  '()                            ;; no keywords
  '(("[." . 'font-lock-operator) ;; some operators
    ("]" . 'font-lock-operator))
  '()                      ;; files for which to activate this mode 
  '(paredit-mode)          ;; other functions to call
  "A mode for qtree edits" ;; doc string for this mode
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

They seem to be called *keywords* for [in-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) no more. Whatever they're called, they don't seem to be user-definable.

What you want to do is extremely related to a common way of handling whereas to export with *xelatex* or *pdflatex* [as described on Worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#using-xelatex-for-pdf-export).

The relevant part would be :

```lisp
;; Originally taken from Bruno Tavernier: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/31150/focus=31432
(defun my-auto-tex-cmd ()
  (if (string-match "YOUR_TAG: value1" (buffer-string))
      (do something))
  (if (string-match "YOUR_TAG: value2" (buffer-string))
      (do something else))

(add-hook 'org-export-latex-after-initial-vars-hook 'my-auto-tex-cmd)
```

Comment: Where does the body come from here?

Comment: @Tass: what do you mean ? You probably really want to look at the Worg page, and I con't help you more with elisp I'm afraid.

Comment: I assume with `string-match`, you can match your own tag and extract the body from that.